# How to hand over money in connect account to stripe account, Stripe Payment

Tags: laravel, stripe-payments, laravel-cashier

I am using **Connect Account** in Stripe, to transfer money to members bank accounts in my project.
Transfer is made once a month (on the 5th of each month).

If a member withdraw from my site, I'd like to hand over the money of connect account to a system account(my stripe account) before 5th.

What can I do? What api would I use?

PS: My project is running on Laravel.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to transfer funds from a Connected Account back to the Platform, in the case they want to leave your Platform. There are 2 ways to do that:

- [Reversing a transfer](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/charges-transfers#reversing-transfers). This way you can send back a specific transfer that was made to the Connected Account. Note that it is limited up to the amount of the target transfer.
- [Debiting accounts](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/account-debits). This is a more powerful tool, but will only work with Express and Custom accounts. There’s more conditions too.